# Google MapsSDK for Android failed to load maps module

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm using [Google MapsSDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk) to show a map view. But map is not loaded and I get the exception from logcat:

```
Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0
Failed to load maps module, use legacy
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:67)     
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzbz.zzc(Unknown Source:35)                                                                                                          
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzbz.zzb(Unknown Source:32)                                                                                                      
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzbz.zza(Unknown Source:14)                                                                                                  
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source:4)                                                                                                          
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source:10)                                                                                                         
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:6)                                                                                                           
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:1)                                                                                                      
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source:26)
...
```

Happy to add Manifest or other files if needed.

Comment: Hello! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for you to increase your chances of getting help. Also please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to properly ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is Google Automotive Service which installed in AAOS does not support MapsSDK.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).